# inserting csv file with different amount of columns into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Trying to insert some data from a csv file using php command fcsvget into a mysql table but coming up short can anyone tell me where im going wrong. im getting no data going in and errors when loading the page.

the csv file has different header names and amount of columns that the table it is going into.

here is my code so far.

```
<?php

// set local variables
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","db","password") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");

// connect to mysql and select database or exit 
mysql_select_db("db", $connect);

// loop content of csv file, using comma as delimiter

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
$Product_ID = $data[0];
$Model = $data[1];

// entry insert
$query = "INSERT into products_test  (products_id, products_model) VALUES '$Product_ID', $Model";


mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_affected_rows() <= 0) {

// no rows where affected by update query
}
} else {
// entry doesn't exist continue or insert...
}

mysql_free_result($result);
}

fclose($handle);
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your code.. The

```
    } else {
     // entry doesn't exist continue or insert...
    }
```

Has no effect as there is no IF started for that. The one

```
   if (mysql_affected_rows() <= 0) {

    // no rows where affected by update query
  }
```

Is already closed before 'Else ' statement. I could not get in to your query but this is what I got in first look

Comment: got rid of them bits, error is gone but nothinginserted, thanks ill mess around some more.

Comment: if I echo $Product_ID; i get 'Product_ID'2055332391621112073922timedia!
'45937721684786886379388637948863795886379679395867939607 its getting some values with '' and not others

Answer (score 0):

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "|")) !== false) {
$Product_ID =  $data[0];
$Model = $data[1];
$HighPic = $data[2];
$ManuId = $data[3];
$parent_id = $data[7];
$Image = $data[13];
$Price = $data[14];
$Supplier = $data[15];
$Stock = $data[17];



// entry insert
$query = "INSERT into products_test (products_id, products_model, products_image, manufacturers_id, products_parent_id, icecat_manfimg, products_price, icecatcode, products_quantity) VALUES ($Product_ID, $Model, $HighPic, $ManuId, $parent_id, $Image, $Price, $Supplier, $Stock)" ;

mysql_query($query);
} 

mysql_free_result($result);


fclose($handle);
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```